# Getting TFS Triggered Build Git Branch

Tags: git, xaml, tfs

I have a TFS 2013u4 Git build definition which defines a repository, default repo, and CI monitored repos in its Source Settings. Using methods described elsewhere, I'm able to retrieve the default branch name from the build definition within my custom build xaml, but I need to find a way to determine the name of the branch which triggered a CI build.

For example:

My build definition lists BranchA as default, and lists BranchA, BranchB, BranchC, and BranchD as monitored branches for CI Triggered builds.

Say someone commits a change to BranchD; this commit will in turn trigger this build definition to fire. How, within my custom build XAML, can I determine that it was a commit on BranchD which triggered this build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property within an **IBuildDetail** object called **SourceGetVersion**. When a build definition is manually executed or triggered using the default branch defined in the build definition, then this property simply returns 'T', but if the build definition was triggered by a commit to a monitored branch, then this property is set to the branch name (plus a few other minor details).

I simply parse the value of this property and I'm able to determine exactly which branch triggered the build definition.

Answer (score 0):

No, this can't be achieved through Git build definition for now. There's no way to limit the CI trigger to a specific folder within the repo.

And there has been a featured request in UserVoice. You can vote up for it.

> **Allow GIT CI Builds to monitor changes only in a specific subdirectory
>   of a Repo**
>   https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5279254-allow-git-ci-builds-to-monitor-changes-only-in-a-s

Comment: This isn't quite what i was asking for. The request in UserVoice is to identify the precise subfolder in a branch where a change was made. All i need to know is the branch name itself. I actually did find a solution, see my reply.